# How to uniformly merge two lists into a dictionary

Tags: python

I have two lists, list1 and list2. I want to create a dict in which list1 is the keys and list2 is divided equally between them. I do not care which element in list2 is associated to in list1. I only care that they will spread uniformly.

for example:

```
list1 = ['a','b','c']
list2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
result = {'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6], 'c':[7,8]}
```

I thought about doing the following list comprehension:

```
num_list2_per_list1 = len(list2)//len(list1)
result_dict = { list1_member : list2[idx*num_list2_per_list1 : (1+idx)*num_list2_per_list1] for idx, list1_member in enumerate(list1) }
```

But this will not work if len(list2) < len(list1). Is there a way to fix this or do I have to make an if statement and split the code?

For example:

```
list1 = ['a','b','c']
list2 = [1,2]
result = {'a':[1], 'b':[2], 'c':[]}
```

Comment: What's the expected output if len(list2) < len(list1)?

Comment: result = {'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5], 'c':[6, 7,8]} - why is this not good ? u should explain your needs better

Comment: @OhadtheLad, Your result is good... I just want it split evenly, I do not care how

Comment: @jhpratt, if len(list2)<len(list1) I would expect some keys to hold an empty list

Comment: I updated the question with both your remarks. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the num_list2_per_list1 as follows the result will be correct

```
num_list2_per_list1 = (len(list2) + len(list1)-1 )//len(list1)
result_dict = { list1_member : list2[idx*num_list2_per_list1 : (1+idx)*num_list2_per_list1] for idx, list1_member in enumerate(list1) }
```

Test runs:

```
list1 = ['a','b','c']
list2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
result = {'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6], 'c':[7,8,9]}

list1 = ['a','b','c']
list2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
result = {'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6], 'c':[7,8]}

list1 = ['a','b','c']
list2 = [1,2]
result = {'a':[1], 'b':[2], 'c':[]}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is one approach.

Using `enumerate`

**Ex:**

```
list1 = ['a','b','c']
list2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
l = len(list1)
result = {}
for i, v in enumerate(range(0, len(list2), l)):
    result[list1[i]] = list2[v: v+l]
print(result)
```

---

Using `zip`

```
for key, v in zip(list1, range(0, len(list2), l)):
    result[key] = list2[v: v+l]
```

**Output:**

```
{'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6], 'c': [7, 8]}
```

---

*Edit as per comment*

```
from itertools import zip_longest  #python2 izip_longest
list1 = ['a','b','c']
list2 = [1,2]

result = {}
if len(list1) > len(list2):
    for key, value in zip_longest(list1, list2, fillvalue=[]):
        result[key] = value
else:
    l = len(list1)
    for key, v in zip(list1, range(0, len(list2), l)):
        result[key] = list2[v: v+l]
print(result)
```

Comment: Both your approaches fail for list1=['a','b','c'] with list2=[1,2]. I would like result to be {'a':[1], 'b':[2], 'c':[]} but your outcome will be {'a':[1,2]}